# Ruby using class from "namespace"

Tags: ruby, namespaces, rubygems

I am using Ruby to create some simple project, and I am following RubyGems project structure. In my codebase I have two classes in different "namespaces":

```
lib
  u
    x
      class_a.rb
  m
    p
      class_b.rb
```

I am using nested modules for this classes, so ClassA is in module X which is in module U.

While requiring `ClassA` inside `ClassB` I can use it by referecing it with `U::X::ClassA`. I wonder if there is any pattern that will let me just typing `ClassA`, without full namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
module M::P
  ClassA = U::X::ClassA 
end
```

defining `ClassA` as a constant inside `P`. It's not a good practise, but you can do it..

IMO, just use `U::X::ClassA`.

Answer (score 0):

Two comments in advance:

- I agree to Fede, IMO, just use U::X::ClassA.
- the namespace in ruby is independent from the file structure. So your example may explain what you want, but it does not give a code example.

That said, you may build a minimal example like this:

```
module U
  module X
    class Class_a
    end
  end
end
module M
  module P
    class Class_b
      include U::X
      def initialize
        a = U::X::Class_a.new ##you want replace this with:
        #a= Class_a.new
      end
    end
  end
end

M::P::Class_b.new
```

[Fedes solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40333347/676874) with `Class_a = U::X::Class_a` would look like:

```
module U
  module X
    class Class_a
    end
  end
end
module M
  module P
    Class_a = U::X::Class_a ##<- define here the local version
    class Class_b
      def initialize
        a= Class_a.new
      end
    end
  end
end

M::P::Class_b.new
```

Another possibility is to include the module that contains the class:

```
module U
  module X
    class Class_a
    end
  end
end
module M
  module P
    class Class_b
      include U::X  #<- Include the module
      def initialize
        a= Class_a.new
      end
    end
  end
end

M::P::Class_b.new
```

Attention: This solution will include all classes and constants of the module `U::X`. This may be a solution you need, but it may also be wrong for your purpose.